# log10 of a Vector3f (Eigen Libs)

Tags: eigen, logarithm

I need to calculate the log10 of a Vector3f.
I have tried:

```
Eigen::Vector3f valsingn = svd.singularValues()/svd.singularValues()(0);
valsingn = valsingn.log10();
```

But it doesn't work.

```
main.cpp:145:27: error: ‘Eigen::Vector3f {aka class Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1>}’ has no member named ‘log10’; did you mean ‘log’?
     valsingn = valsingn.log10();
```

Is there a way to calculate the `log10` with this vector?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The simple way that would allow Eigen to still utilize SIMD (I assume it's enabled) would be to do a simple change of bases:

```
valsingn = valsingn.array().log() / log(10.0);
```

Alternatively, you can pass `log10` as a unary expression:

```
 valsingn.unaryExpr(&log10); // You may have to wrap 
                             // log10 in a function of
                             // your own depending on
                             // the log10 overloads
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move to the [array world](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialArrayClass.html) for pure coefficient-wise functions:

```
Vector3f v, w;
w = v.array().log10();
w = log10(v.array());
Arrayt3f a, b;
b = a.log10();
b = log10(a);
```

Comment: Does this compile for you? Which version of Eigen do you use? In which file is `log10` defined?

Comment: @m7913d `log10` was added in Eigen 3.3.

Comment: @ggael Is there a SIMD `log10`? It's not listed in the [dox](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__CoeffwiseMathFunctions.html).

Comment: No, but the question was for Vector3f, which is not vectorized anyway.